# Show binary data uisng codeigniter

Tags: algorithm, codeigniter

We are trying to do a MLM binary structure using CodeIgniter. But unable to do that. If someone help me then i will be glad. I have given the database image, Binary Tree Image, and also all the required code. just check and tell me how can I put the values in binary tree in a correct format. I want to show only 3 layer like the image after that we don't need more layer. The main Parent node is the user code of the logged in user. Hope you understand my point.

**Image of Binary Tree**

[image: Binary Tree View]

[image: Database]

**View Code**

```
<div class="tree">
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">001</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">002</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                    <a href="#">004</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">008</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">009</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

                    <li><a href="#">005</a>
                    <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">010</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">010</a></li>
                </ul></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">003</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">006</a>
                    <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">012</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">013</a></li>
                </ul></li>
                    <li><a href="#">007</a>
                    <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">014</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">015</a></li>
                </ul></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**Model Code**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class TreeModel extends CI_Model {

    public function get_parent_node()
    {
        $this->load->database();

        $query = $this->db->select('ref_code')
                          ->group_by('ref_code')
                          ->get('tbl_tree');
        $result = $query->result_array();

        return $result;
    }

    public function get_child_node($parent_node)
    {
        $this->load->database();

        $query = $this->db->where('ref_code', $parent_node)
                      ->get('tbl_tree');
        $result = $query->result_array();

        return $result;
    }
}
```

**Controller Code**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->model('TreeModel');

        $parent_node = $this->TreeModel->get_parent_node();

        $complete_tree = array();

        foreach($parent_node as $parent):
            $child_node = $this->TreeModel->get_child_node($parent['ref_code']);
            $parent['childs'] = $child_node;
            foreach($child_node as $child):
                $child_node_1 = $this->TreeModel->get_child_node($child['ref_code']);
                $parent['childs_1'][] = $child_node_1;
            endforeach;
            array_push($complete_tree, $parent);
        endforeach;


        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($complete_tree);
        die();

        $data['tree'] = $complete_tree;
        $this->load->view('welcome_message', $data);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think if you search for parent/child menus, parent/child trees, etc. you will find that this kind of display (or sorting) has been covered many times. The only difference here is that you have the left or right designation, but in all other cases you just need a recursive function. I've got a class that does what you need, minus the left/right thing, but you'll find your answer many times here on SO.

Comment: yah i searched that and also checked. But unable to get the result. It will be much appreciable if you can help me with this code or much clean code that other what they have.

Comment: I'm just finishing up my break. Might be able to help you in a couple hours, but I can't do it immediately.

Comment: sure sir take your time, we are not in a hurry

Comment: OK, question. You are just looking for the nested list right? Also, your data in your database table is not exactly a parent child relationship shown in the image of the binary tree. I've made a nested list that shows that data in a parent/child relationship. If this is exactly what you want I will post my answer.

Comment: I deleted my answer, since it wasn't what you wanted. You said you want to "retrieve on the view code", and I have no idea what you want. I'd have to have you fully explain what you're trying to do, or I won't be able to help.

Comment: Hi I explained well that my table structure is like what i given and i want it in view code like what i given.

Comment: @Fairy Dancer can you help me on this